# SignalR "No Connection with that ID"

Tags: apache, asp.net-core, ubuntu-18.04, asp.net-core-signalr

I have an asp.net core 2.1 web app, which is deployed to Ubuntu 18.04 LAMP server as a self-contained app.

There is a Chat page, created with SignalR and on localhost everything works fine.

However, when I connect to http://www.limboworld.net /real website/ 
and go to the Chat page and inspect the Console using developer tools I see the following:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=12JxhgoDtpXwrMFX7Z5oJ6MlkpkuN0How

When clicking on the link http://www.limboworld.net/hubs/chat?id=8rE5uw4Ck9PIpoaCF_KuMA I get "No Connection with that ID".

According to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html, I tried adding the

`ProxyPass "/ws2/"  "ws://echo.websocket.org/"`

directive, but I am not sure what causes the problem.

Maybe there is some problem with my code and that is why I am posting this here even though I only tried configuring Apache.

Would someone please help me remove the error message in the Chrome developer tools console?

Any help on why this is not working is appreciated.

Comment: Please share the code snippet you are using to establish connection to hub.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I found this [link](https://community.bitwarden.com/t/websocket-fails-behind-apache-proxy/3696/3) and changed the configuration according to it, and now it connects the websocket, but now I get this error: `signalr.min.js:13 Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Websocket closed with status code: 1006 ()'.`. I will post the code snippet later.

Comment: Here is the code snippet, used to establish connection to hub: ```$(function () {

            setScreen(false);

            var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                .withUrl("/hubs/chat")
                .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
                .build();

            

            connection.start().catch(err => console.error(err.toString())).then(function () {
                registerClientMethods(connection);
                registerEvents(connection);
            });

        });```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in a comment above, after changing the apache configuration according to this link: https://community.bitwarden.com/t/websocket-fails-behind-apache-proxy/3696/3, which is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off

    # allow for upgrading to websockets
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://127.0.0.1:5000/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           http://127.0.0.1:5000/$1 [P,L]

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/

    ProxyPass /hubs/chat ws://127.0.0.1:5000/hubs/chat
    ProxyPassReverse /hubs/chat ws://127.0.0.1:5000/hubs/chat

</VirtualHost>
```

The browser was connecting to the websocket.
Now I had a different error: `signalr.min.js:13 Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Websocket closed with status code: 1006 ()'.`

This article: http://blog.etrupja.com/2018/08/the-antiforgery-token-could-not-be-decrypted/ helped me solve the problem.

I had to install a nuget package with the command `Install-Package Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File` and after that
add the following code to the Startup.cs file:

```
ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
//your code here
services.AddDataProtection()
.SetApplicationName("your-app-name")
.PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo("your-path-here"));
//your code here
}
```

This effectively removed all errors in the Chrome Developer Tools Console.

I hope this helps someone with a similar problem.

Cheers!